# How to use SHA-1 hash as AES key

Tags: java, arrays, oop, aes, sha1

I want to combine hashing and encryption for better security. So can I use a hash key generated from SHA-1 as a key in AES.
For example, I have a password "50", I calculate SHA-1 hash for it (e1822db470e60d090affd0956d743cb0e7cdf113), and I want to feed those bytes as key for AES-128.
What things I need to care while implementing this?
Should I just truncate after 128 bits or do some kind of folding?

Here the code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
public class MessageDigestExample {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
String input = "This is a message";
MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
System.out.println("input : " + input);
hash.update(Utils.toByteArray(input));
System.out.println("digest : " + Utils.toHex(hash.digest()));
} }
```

Comment: Depending on from where you got the string to hash this may have weak security. But if the source is OK, both truncation and folding (with XOR) would be fine.

Comment: Please refer this answer...it has the code to convert a password to key using PBKDF2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015144/1235935

Answer (score 0):

While AES-128 provides sufficient security, using a key from SHA-1 probably isn't.

Aside from that:

Your Question is more a debate, than easy to answer. I would like to point you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863149/10353914

With the information provided, your question kinda gets obsolete - better use PBKDF2 where you can set the output hash size to 128 bits.